# How to hide the section numbering from the TOC

Tags: latex

I want to remove the chapter number from the table of content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
 \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  \sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}% Add section to ToC
  %Add more content here, if needed.
}



\fakesection{Chapter 1: Introduction}
\begin{center}
\huge Chapter 1 \\
\huge Introduction
\end{center}


\subsection{Introduction}
Hello welcome.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to hide the section using `*` at the beginning but didn't work.

[EDITED]
the chapter number hiding problem is but now there is a bigger issue. How am I gonna change subsection{introduction} number from 8.1 to 1.1?

Is there a way to break the chain of the sections ....similar to page break?

[image]

Comment: Instead of recreating fake chapters, wouldn't it make more sense to use a documentclass which supports chapters?

Comment: documentclass is article not accepting the \chapter() .....that's why I used fakesection()

Comment: That's why I am suggesting to use a documentclass which is accepting `\chapter`. For example `report` or `book` instead of `article`.

Comment: I can't do that now. it will mess up my whole document writings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `\numberline{\thesection}` you explicitly add a number to your "chapter" entry in the toc. If you don't want this, remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}
   \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
  \sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}% Add section to ToC
  %Add more content here, if needed.
}


\fakesection{Declaration}

\fakesection{Chapter 1: Introduction}
\begin{center}
\huge Chapter 1 \\
\huge Introduction
\end{center}


\subsection{Introduction}
Hello welcome.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I did tried to remove the whole line from \protect.  that's why it didn't work. But now you nailed it. Thanks bro.

Comment: although it solved the problem but created a bigger issue ..... how can I break the chain of section ? ... want the introduction to be 1.1 but now it is 8.1 ....!!!

Comment: @Mzi You are using `\refstepcounter{section}` in your fake chapter. This increases the section counter, so your numbering will be wrong. If you don't want this, don't do this.

Comment: I removed it now showing introduction as 0.1 ......that's not okey!! susbsection{introduction} has to be 1.1 ....How am I gonna do that?

Comment: OMG!!! ..... You are absolutely a lifesaver!!! ... how did you do that!!! ... thanks soooo much...  it worked !! I am really grateful to you....